# Angular2 how to set app root path independently from html base url

Tags: angular, typo3, angular2-router3

I'm building an angular2 application/widget that will be embedded into TYPO3 as a plugin that can be inserted on any content page. This means it could end up at different root paths e.g.:

```
/page1/app
/page/subpage/subpage/whatever
```

The global base url (base href=..) is already set by TYPO3 and can't be changed. How can I give angular some kind of root prefix so that it can build up its routes correctly?

I'm using the new router as documented here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually there is a solution in the angular docs but it's pretty hard to find. It's possible to set the base url in angular without using a `<base>` tag.
So you just have to set the base url to a global JavaScript variable using fluid and then provide it to angular in the app module.

**Fluid:**

```
<script>
   var app_base_url = '<f:uri.page pageUid="{currentPageUid}" />';
</script>
```

**Angular:**

```
declare var app_base_url;

import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue:app_base_url}]
})
class AppModule {}
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/APP_BASE_HREF-let.html

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer

Comment: Also it cloud be more suitable to use key `--base-href` while build, example: `ng build --base-href=/myapp`

Comment: @EugeneKirin it is important that the base-href ends with `/` otherwise browsers ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

I would advice not to use the `baseURL` config attribute. It is a bit outdated and leads to some problems, like yours.

You can set

```
config.absRefPrefix = /
```

All links will be prepended with / now and will also work.

Comment: Since TYPO3 7.6 it's possible to use `config.absRefPrefix = auto` which is configuring the accordant path automatically. However, this alone does not solve the problem with Angular2 routing.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that would solve my problem. Also this TYPO3 installation is quite old and I can't change this setup.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest versions of angular I get an error about the variable, so I use a data-attribute instead

```
<body data-base-url="whatever/"> ...
```

Angular:

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue:documnent.body.dataset.baseUrl}]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your web-server is handling the URL already and thus it's not delegated to the Angular2 routing. To overcome this, you have to use a different `LocationStrategy` in Angular.

What you're looking for is called `HashLocationStrategy` to create routes like `/page1/app/#/angular-controller/` where `/page1/app/` is served from the web-server and `/angular-controller/` is the first argument to your Angular2 application logic.

Adjust your module declaration (e.g. `app.module.ts`)

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {
  LocationStrategy,
  HashLocationStrategy
} from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Find more details in the [Angular2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/HashLocationStrategy-class.html) about that (the example was taken from there as well).

Comment: The examples are based on Angular 2.0, if you're still on some RC-level, consider upgrading to final first. A lot changed between RC4 and final for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I really would like to use the "real" urls. Actually I found a solution that works with the default Strategy and will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Look at APP_BASE_HREF in this case, basically in Angular2 and above, you can override the provider like this, this is the example in Angular.io showing this case:

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/my/app'}]
})
class AppModule {}
```

So in that case the APP_BASE_HREF will be replaced by /my/app, so you can do it for each module separately...This just apply within Angular application...

For more info, looking at these pages on Angular doc:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/PathLocationStrategy-class.html

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/APP_BASE_HREF-let.html